# In a group, is every element in that group the inverse of some element in the same group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In a group, $<G,*>$, is every element in that group the inverse of some element in the same group ?

I mean, if I define $f:G \to G$ such that $f(x)=x^{-1}$, is f a bijective function ?

If so, how can we prove it ?

---

Since $x^{-1}$ is unique, $f$ is one-to-one, but I don't know how to show the surjectivity of the function.

Comment: What have you tried? **Hint:** Use  $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$ to show $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @ArpitKansal Actually, I almost couldn't do anything about the subjectivity of the function.

Comment: "I almost couldn't do anything about the subjectivity of the function"  Why not $f(x^{-1}) = x$ so... it's surjective.

Comment: @fleablood "Why not " ? Dude, I couldn't see it, that is the point.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks by the way.

Comment: Off tangent, but I must object to the use of "other" or "another" in the questions and answers. It's perfectly possible that $x^{-1} = x$.  That doesn't make any difference to the answer but it's inaccurate to say $x^{-1}$ is "another" element.

Comment: So Arpit Kansal's comment *did* help you?

Comment: @fleablood i saw the same fact; not a cause for objection though is it? It simply changes the answer of the question.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't even notice that Arpit Kansal edited his/her comment.

Comment: By "objection" I meant in terms of language.  It doesn't change the answer.  $f$ being a bijection does not mean that $f(x) \ne x$ for all $x$.  (Not even remotely).  But $identity^{-1} = identity$ and for any $a$ so that $a^2 = indentity$ than $a^{-1} = a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

It is part of the axioms of a group that for each $x\in G$ there is an inverse $x^{-1}$. You can check from the definition of the inverse that $x=(x^{-1})^{-1}$ - this gives surjectivity.

Answer (score 2):

> **Proposition.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$, $g\colon Y\to Z$ be functions.
>
> $(i)$  If $g\circ f$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective as well.
>
> $(ii)$ If $g\circ f$ is injective, $f$ is injective as well.

*Proof.* Exercise.

> **Corollary.** Let $f\colon X\to X$ be involution, i.e. $f\circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$. Then $f$ is bijective.

Now, since $x\cdot x^{-1} = x^{-1}\cdot x = e_G$, $\forall x\in G$, by uniqueness of inverse we have $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$. Thus, function $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is involution and hence bijective by the above corollary.

Comment: This answer might be more general than needed in this particular case, but nevertheless, these are one those facts everyone should be familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still a freshman year mathematic student, and I'm having hard time about the terminology you use.

Comment: @Leth, I was freshman when I was introduced to this. If you are worried about what involution is, it's exactly what I wrote, $f^2 = \operatorname{id}$. If there is something else you'd like me to clarify, feel free to ask.

Comment: Actually, proposition I wrote is completely superfluous, $f\circ f = \operatorname{id}$ immediately implies $f^{-1} = f$ by definition. But, oh well...

Comment: does $id_x$  stands for identity function ?

Comment: @Leth, yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks you, I got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a group is closed under inversion. This means that for every element $g\in G$, there is an inverse $g^{-1}\in G$. Applying this to $g^{-1}$ implies there is an inverse, call it $h$, for $g^{-1}$. So $gh^{-1}$ is the identity, and therefore $g=h$. Thus we have shown that $g$ is the inverse of some other element of the group, namely $g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Injective:

If $y^{-1} = x$ and $z^{-1} = x$ then $y = z$.

Pf: $y^{-1} = x \& z^{-1} = x \implies yx = 1 \& zx = 1 \implies y = yxx^{-1}=1x^{-1} = x^{-1} \& z=zxx^{-1}=1x^{-1}=x^{-1}\implies y = z = x^{-1}$

Surjective:

For every $x$,  $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$.  Pf:  $(x^{-1})x = x(x^{-1}) = 1$.  So $x = (x^{-1})^{-1}$.